# Claimed promo code content only available on other device

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-ios, itunes-store

I've got an app with in-app puchases made with ReactNative and [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap).
Restoring and making a new in-app purchase works as expected, but if content is unlocked with promo codes, it has a strange behavior.

I have multiple devices on the same Apple ID.

If I claim a promo code on device 1, and restore purchases to unlock it - it does not work.
If I then restore on device 2, it works, and the content is unlocked. If I claim a promo code on device 2, it does not work - but restoring on device 1 unlocks the content.

If I restore on device 3, the content from both promo codes is unlocked.

Restoring:

```
let purchases = await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases();
let prodArray = [];
purchases.forEach(purchase => {
  prodArray.push(purchase.productId);
});
AsyncStorage.setItem('Purchases', JSON.stringify(prodArray));
```

To sum up, promo codes kinda unlocks the content, but not on the device it was claimed on.

Is there anyone who have experienced something like this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show relevant code; how do you process restoration and how do you process purchases

Comment: I have updated my question, with the restoration. Apart from promo codes claimed on the same device, the code works as expected. I have not added purchase code - It's not used for this process.

Comment: Purchasing code is important. It is used for promo unlocks and restoration; restoration is basically the same as a purchase. You must ensure that you create a payment transaction observer as soon as your app launches.

Comment: Okay - there is something to look into. But how does it explain why the claimed promo code content works on second device? Even if I uninstall on the first device and restore - it is only promo codes made on other devices that get unlocked.

Comment: It sounds like a difference between how you process transactions (which is done on the device where the code is redeemed) vs check the receipt for existing transactions (which is done in the other device). Unfortunately things are further complicated because you are using React Native so you are somewhat isolated from the underlying StoreKit operations, also is the code for a consumable or non-consumable purchase item?

Comment: All items is for non-consumable. The transaction has to processed in order for it to show up after restore on the second device. I don't get how thats different on the first device, since it's clearly processed, and it's the same code that does the restoring.